# calculates (without using L'Hopital) the following limit

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I don't understand how to calculate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to7}\frac{1}{x-7}\int_7^x\sqrt{t^2+9}dt $$
 without using the L'Hopital rule [the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrsw3.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Comment: It shuold be $$2\sqrt{14}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please show what you have tried - this is not a site meant to have people solve homework for you. Also, please use [MathJax][1] to present the formulae equations. 
  [1]: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you don't want to use l'Hopital, you'll be in trouble with that limit.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Using $f(t)=\sqrt{t^2+9}$
$$\int_7^x f(t)dt=F(x)-F(7)$$ Then what you are asked to compute is $$\lim_{x\to 7}\frac{F(x)-F(7)}{x-7}=F'(x)|_{x=7}=f(7)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use mean value theorem. There exists $\xi \in [7,x]$ such that $$\int_7^x \sqrt{t^2+9}dt = (x-7) \sqrt{\xi^2+9}$$ 
You don't really need to know the value of $\xi$, the fact that $\xi \in [7,x]$ is enough.